# CORS not allowed use a POST method

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

My application is divied by two servers gulp and tomcat.
On front is AngularJS on back Spring boot.
Gulp working on port 3000 and tomcat on 8080.

I send request from localhost:3000 to my api (localhost:8080/api/register) using POST method and my spring response HTTP Status code 403.

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I'm tried add to controllers Annotation @CrossOrigin but this didn't help.

Also, I added to my WebConfig the following code:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000").allowedMethods("OPTIONS","POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE");
            }
        };
    }
```

The above code help but only for GET request.
Any idea why it's doesn't work ?

Comment: Do you have any custom filters defined? Anything that extends `GenericFilterBean` or some such class?

Comment: I've got a CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter which send CSRF token to angular.

Comment: I've ran into issues where if I have a Filter in place, then the CORS stuff doesn't work via WebMvcConfigurer or the annotation. I have to add all the CORS header info in my filter. You might try that and see if you get better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following code to the configuration of tomcat.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter